# Commit logs under cdc_raw folder getting corrupted

Tags: cassandra, change-data-capture

I am using cassandra 3.11.12 version. I have recently enabled cdc_raw in cassandra configuration and created new key space and table with `WITH cdc=true;` and after inserting values ran the alter command.

Now the i am performing nodetool flush. Then seeing this error.

```
ERROR [CdcCommitlogProcessor:4] 2023-07-10 09:22:14,726 CommitLogReadHandlerImpl.java:256 - Unrecoverable error when reading commit log
org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReadHandler$CommitLogReadException: Encountered bad header at position 4453655 of commit log /var/lib/cassandra/cdc_raw/CommitLog-6-1688977610814.log, with bad position but valid CRC
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegmentReader$SegmentIterator.computeNext(CommitLogSegmentReader.java:113)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegmentReader$SegmentIterator.computeNext(CommitLogSegmentReader.java:84)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReader.readCommitLogSegment(CommitLogReader.java:240)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReader.readCommitLogSegment(CommitLogReader.java:141)
    at com.datastax.oss.cdc.agent.CommitLogReaderServiceImpl$1.run(CommitLogReaderServiceImpl.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.NamedThreadFactory.lambda$threadLocalDeallocator$0(NamedThreadFactory.java:84)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Initially i thought issue is with the commit logs.

1. stopped cass
2. removed commit log files
3. start cass

But still seeing same error when i do nodetool flush. Not able to identify where the issue lies.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to fix the issue. Two changes i have made.

1. I have downgraded my cassandra version to 3.11.11.
2. I have put commitlog and cdc_raw in 2 different locations. After moving commitlog to /var/lib/cassandra. I have stopped seeing the errors.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The symptoms you described indicate to me that you have misconfigured something when you enabled CDC.

Looking at [the code for the `CommitLogSegmentReader.java` class](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.11.12/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/commitlog/CommitLogSegmentReader.java), it runs into issues reading the commit log segment. Without details of how you've configured the node, my best guess is that commitlog segments are getting overwritten while they are being read.

Make sure that `commitlog_directory` and `cdc_raw_directory` are configured with two distinct directories. They cannot be set to the same directory. Cheers!